# Go : How to Set same Cookie on all pages?

Tags: google-app-engine, session, cookies, go, session-cookies

After logging in my url changes to /login/ and cookie gets set.
After setting cookie need to redirect the page on home page (url : /homePage/) other than /login/.

How to set same cookie in all pages?

Comment: I find that using something like Gorilla Sessions can really help with this (http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions)

Comment: with go-google-app-engine ?

Comment: I've edited my answer with the Gorilla web toolkit recommended GAE setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt [`CookieJar`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/) library to manage a store of cookies (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756782/go-http-post-and-use-cookies) answer for some pointers), but it's probably easier to use something like [Gorilla Sessions](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions) from the [Gorilla Web Toolkit](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/).

There is also some GAE specific setup (from http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/):

> For Google App Engine, create a directory tree inside your app and clone the repository there:
>
> $ cd myapp
> $ mkdir -p github.com/gorilla
> $ cd github.com/gorilla
> $ git clone git://github.com/gorilla/mux.git

The last line of that example is specific to the [`mux`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) package. You would replace it with:

> git clone git://github.com/gorilla/sessions.git

A quick example:

Define your cookie store:

```
import (
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    "net/http"
)

// Authorization Key
var authKey = []byte{
    0x70, 0x23, 0xbd, 0xcb, 0x3a, 0xfd, 0x73, 0x48,
    0x46, 0x1c, 0x06, 0xcd, 0x81, 0xfd, 0x38, 0xeb,
    0xfd, 0xa8, 0xfb, 0xba, 0x90, 0x4f, 0x8e, 0x3e,
    0xa9, 0xb5, 0x43, 0xf6, 0x54, 0x5d, 0xa1, 0xf2,
}

// Encryption Key
var encKey = []byte{
    0x31, 0x98, 0x3E, 0x1B, 0x00, 0x67, 0x62, 0x86,
    0xB1, 0x7B, 0x60, 0x01, 0xAA, 0xA8, 0x76, 0x44,
    0x00, 0xEB, 0x56, 0x04, 0x26, 0x9B, 0x5A, 0x57,
    0x29, 0x72, 0xA1, 0x62, 0x5B, 0x8C, 0xE9, 0xA1,
}

var store = sessions.NewCookieStore(authKey, encKey)

func initSession(r *http.Request) *sessions.Session {
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "my_cookie")
    if session.IsNew {
        session.Options.Domain = "example.org"
        session.Options.MaxAge = 0
        session.Options.HttpOnly = false
        session.Options.Secure = true
    }
    return session
}
```

And then, in your page handlers you just load the cookie, set any options you like and re-save it:

```
func ViewPageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session := initSession(r)
    session.Values["page"] = "view"
    session.Save(r, w)
....
```

Hope that helps.